# NullPointerException when declaring method from another class

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception, declaration

I've been trying to work around this NullPointerException issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LinearSearcher.<init>(LinearSearcher.java:12)
    at DemoSearches.main(DemoSearches.java:4)
```

through researching, I found that this exception occurs when you declare a reference type but don't create an object. In my case it is when I am trying to declare `LinearSearcher`

I've tried to understand this with my code but i'm having difficulties

Code for LinearSearcher:

```
public class LinearSearcher implements Searcher {

private int[] numbers;

public LinearSearcher() {

  numbers[0] = 1; // Line 12 Here
  numbers[1] = 10;
  numbers[2] = 20;
  numbers[3] = 30;
  numbers[4] = 40;
  numbers[5] = 50;
  numbers[6] = 60;
  numbers[7] = 70;
  numbers[8] = 80;
  numbers[9] = 90;

}


public int searchFor(int key) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if (numbers[i] == key) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return NOT_FOUND;
}


public void display() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  }
 }
}
```

Class where LinearSearcher is declared:

```
public class DemoSearches {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    LinearSearcher search = new LinearSearcher(); // Line 4 Here

    search.display();


    search.searchFor(50);
    search.searchFor(100);

 }
}
```

Comment: suppose `private int[] numbers` is not initialized.

Answer (score 4):

`numbers` is `null` because you haven't initialized it. You can change

```
private int[] numbers;
```

to

```
private int[] numbers = { 1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
```

and eliminate the problem. Other solution, add

```
numbers = new int[10];
```

Before your current assignments.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the `numbers` array so when you try to access it in the `LinearSearcher` constructor you are trying to access a nonexistent array. So an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `numbers = new int[10];` before doing `numbers[0]` etc. This will create the object so it can be used.